# Использовать svg из разметки в качестве фона

Tags: html, css, svg

Как использовать `#bg` в качестве фона `section`?

https://jsfiddle.net/42nn4b49/2/

```css
div {
  width: 4em;
}

section {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  background: url(#bg); /* не работает */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="-4 -4 8 8" id="bg">
    <circle r="4" />
  </svg>
</div>

<section></section>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/39916145/4928642)

Comment: попробуй как-то так background: url(../img/name.svg);

Comment: @FrankSinatra, не, мне нужно именно из разметки.

Comment: там он костылем лепил, а чем тебе мой вариант не подходит?
плюс он так как элемент страницы пилил

Comment: @FrankSinatra, у меня svg на d3.js собирается на странице. И надо её отправить в фон другого элемента.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39916145/4928642

Answer (score 3):

Ну если не подходит вариант со вставкой из внешнего svg файла `background: url(../img/name.svg);`, то svg можно вставлять инлайново, [как пример](https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/HGJms)

```
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><circle cx='15' cy='15' r='10' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
```

Только нужно объявить структору svg через атрибут xmlns: `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'`

На счет того чтобы вставить DOM элемент в качестве background, я могу ошибаться, но вроде пока спецификация css не позволяет это сделать. При желании можно костыльнуть например так:

```js
var section = document.querySelector("section");
value = "url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + document.querySelector("svg").outerHTML.replace(/\r|\n/g, '') + "')";
section.style.background = value;
```

```css
div {
  width: 4em;
}

section {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  /* background: url(#bg); устанавливается через js */
}
```

```html
<div>
   <svg viewBox="-4 -4 8 8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="bg">
       <circle r="4" />
   </svg>
</div>

<section class="section"></section>
```

Ну или вообще отказаться от этой идеи и абсолютно спозиционировать svg и section в одном родителе.

Comment: 1. Так я уже поэкспериментировал: https://jsfiddle.net/42nn4b49/9/ 2. Что касается DOM-элемента в фон, есть -moz-element, но это только FF. 3. Я хотел, чтобы у меня dom-элемент сам синхронизировался с фоном при некоторых изменениях - придётся обойтись без этого... А вообще, спасибо за интересный вариант - гораздо интереснее, чем на SO.

Comment: Свойство *-element кажется на 4ую спецификацию перенесли. Оно вроде сейчас работает в chome и mozille. Было бы удобно его использовать

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/element - вроде только FF?

Comment: Да это я подтупил немного, не то свойство в caniuse глянул